# How to resolve : Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="com.library.controller.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.library.dao.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Return Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#aabcde">
<div align="right"><a href="Login.jsp">Logout</a></div>
<table align="center" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tr><th>BookID</th><th>BookName</th><th>Issuedate</th><th>returndate</th></tr>
<c:forEach var="element" items="${list}">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.getBookid}</td><td>${element.getBookname()}</td>  
        <td>${element.getIssuedate()}</td><td>${element.getReturndate()}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The Eclipse IDE is showing red underline and when I focus it the tag is : can not find the library descriptor for http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

Comment: you are getting this error in the editor when looking at the file, or when you run the web app?

Comment: what server you are using  ? what lib you added?

Comment: also post your web.xml 's root tag

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I also use this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

but I don't get any error.

Did you include the `jstl.jar` in your library? If not maybe this causing the problem. And also the 'tld' folder do you have it? And how about your `web.xml` did you map it?

Have a look on the info about [jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for other information.

Comment: try this jar http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar

Answer (score 103):

I know this thread is a year old now but having experienced the same problem I managed to solve the problem by setting a target server for my project.

i.e. right-click on your project and select 'Properties' -> 'Targeted Runtimes' and select the server you going to run your web app on (Tomcat 6 or 7).

Comment: You may also need to right-click in the left margin on the error icon on the taglib definition line of code and select the 'validate' option to get rid of the error after setting the targeted run-time. The Clean and Build option in Eclipse does not seem to re-validate resources.

Comment: I tried this, but I don't see any "target servers"- only jre6 is listed as a target server.  I clicked it and it didn't help.

Comment: In my case Tomcat 6 was already set, unchecking and checking again would do the trick!

Comment: it's working like a charm..

Answer (score 39):

As @ace mentioned you will need the jstl.jar in your project, so if you are using maven, you could add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Most of servers already have this dependency, if you add it using maven it may cause version conflicts (like Method/ClassNotFoundException) if you don't configure the server well, so it's better set a target server for your project, as @willix mentioned.

Comment: This worked for me! The error is gone.

Comment: Add `<scope>provided</scope>` if your deploying server already have.

Answer (score 14):

Try to add like this:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

instead of having

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: does not work for me.

Comment: In my case, I hard-coded it to use "https" instead of "http"... #facepalm

Answer (score 6):

Add both javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar and standard-1.1.2.jar

Comment: If you add both these jar it will work for sure. Thanks...:)

Comment: Add both these jars and add the path at the top of my JSPs; works well for me!

Comment: works for me as well. Initially I had just jstl-api, and the library descriptor wasn't found. It resolved after I added jstl jar

Answer (score 5):

After a couple of hit and trial I use this. This works for me.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

WARNING: As BalusC correctly mentioned, this works for JSTL 1.0.

Comment: That means that you've the old JSTL 1.0 version in your lib. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 3):

You are probably targeting a server without built-in JSTL support (e.g. some version of Tomcat.) You will need to provision your own JSTL tag library.

Answer (score 3):

paste below two jar in your /WEB-INF/lib folder and then go to project properties and go to add jar and select these two jars  then click Ok, Ok

standard.jar, 
jstl-1.0.2.jar

Comment: standard.jar fixed it for me, only in pom didnt worked

Answer (score 3):

I tried "validating" de *.jsp and *.xml files in eclipse with the validate tool.

"right click on directory/file ->- validate" and it worked!

Using eclipse juno.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Using the:**

> standard.jar

Resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do about `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`.

Just go to project and right click then  project menu -> Clean the project error will definitely remove and update maven .

Comment: @Buddhashwar Ojhar Great answer! You are exactly to the point :) I revolved this issue with your solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to write as

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Make sure you have  jstl-1.0 & standard.jar **BOTH** files are placed in a classpath

Answer (score 1):

It will work perfectly when you will place the two required jar files under /WEB-INF/lib folder i.e. 
jstl-1.2.jar
and javax.servlet.jsp under /WEB-INF/lib folder.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.
use below taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and add jstl-1.2.jar

Comment: the simple answer that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

and moreover please let us know why are you importing all these class

```
<%@ page import="com.library.controller.*"%> 
<%@ page import="com.library.dao.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
```

We don't need to include java.lang as it is the default package.

Answer (score 0):

I will throw one more solution into the mix. I downloaded a sample app and it was crimping only on this taglib. Turns out it didn't care for the single quotes around the attributes.

```
<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>
```

Once I changed those and made sure jstl.jar was in the web app, i was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I added jstl jar in a library and added it to build path and deployment assembly but it dint worked.
then i simply copied my jstl jar into lib folder inside webcontent, it worked.
in eclipse lib folder in included to deployment assembly by default