# need clarification on JSTL <c:set> tag

Tags: java, jstl

I'm new in jstl. I was trying to print some value after setting it in a variavle.
Below is the code what I have written. But it's giving output as ${salary}.

Here my code:

```
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:out value="${salary}"/>
```

Please help.

Below is my Jsp file content..

```
<%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %> 
<html>
 <head> 
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
   <title>Insert title here</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
   <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
   <c:out value="${salary}"/> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:out value="${salary}"/>

Comment: Have you included the standard jstl libs?

Comment: What will happen if you change the scope from session to page ?

Comment: I have included only jstl-1.2.jar. Is there anything else need to be included? If I'm changing the scope to page, the o/p remains same.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595511/taglib-prefix-c-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-fails-with-can

Comment: Below is my Jsp file content..<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:out value="${salary}"/>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %>
```

to

```
<%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

and give a try