# What is the library of s:if and how can I add it to project in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I wanna use s:if tag but it occured an error because of it is not added. How can I add it to my project. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `s` is intended to be the prefix for the JSTL (JSP Standard Tag Library).  See [these instructions for enabling JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595511/taglib-prefix-c-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-fails-with-can).  Follow them, but switch the `prefix` of the `taglib` to be `"s"` instead of `"c"`.