# Run jsp in cfm project and error:"jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml"

Tags: java, jsp, coldfusion-9, coldfusionbuilder

I try to write application in Coldfusion Builder 3, using cfm-files and jsp. When I add link with jsp on my index.cfm and try to run my application I see error: HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application. Then I added in project libs jstl and jsp-and this is not solve problem. Somebody, please help!Any idea, how fix this?

index.cfm

```
 <a href="main.jsp">as</a>
```

main.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%
  HttpSession ses = request.getSession(true);
%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <c:redirect url="index.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dunno how JSP works at all (I came to this via the CF tag), but that http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core isn't a live URL any more probably doesn't help. It just redirects to the Java home page. Why  - in the C21st - are you writing new code using JSPs, btw?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595511/taglib-prefix-c-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-fails-with-can. See the first answer.