# JSP Missing Tag Descriptor For Core And SQL

Tags: jsp

I am working on a form processing program to write the user info into a database. However my tag descriptors seem to be missing. My code is follows

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>


<html>
<head>
<title>New Account</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="users" driver="org.sqlite.JDBC"
                   url="users.db" user="" password=""
/>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get these `taglibs` to work? Must I download them? If so, where in the project should I store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taglibs can be found in the jstl library. See this topic about [tag library descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co)

In general you will have to add them to your project.

In case you are using Maven you can do something like:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>${jstl.version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```