# class not found exception Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am starting a new mvcspring project and I am getting an exception seen below. 
I am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMVC threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mkyong.common.controller.HelloWorldController
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiate
```

My dispatcher-servlet is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" 
    class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HelloWorldController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My bean is actually called the correct name, I don't understand the problem. Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The controller it questions is HelloWorldController. Any help for a noob appreciated!!
EDIT: adding controller code and structure of project.

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }

}
```

Here is project structure: http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/spring-mvc-hello-wold.png

Comment: Did you create HelloWorldController? May be post screenshot of your package structure?

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: This looks like Spring 2 tutorial. Since this is not supported anymore, I would not recommend learning this way. I would recommend checking out Spring 3 (or better yet Spring 4).

Spring 3: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: Also, please post your HelloWorldController java code :-)

Comment: Code added and image for project structure!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that strangely it was not a problem with my code but actually that I had not a server assigned to my project. I noticed that the first line in my Jsp had an error on the first line i.e. <%@ taglib....

I then found this and hey presto [How to resolve : Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co)