# How to fix the "can not find the tag library descriptor for http //java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" in a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

I have tried this link below: [How to resolve : Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co)

I added the "javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.jar" to WEB-INF/lib in my project and below is a part of web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

I am using JRE7 if that makes a difference. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I was able to fix the error, turns out the right jar to be added is "jstl-1.2.jar" which is found at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the error, turns out the right jar to be added is "jstl-1.2.jar" which is found at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2