# jsp and jstl core tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>CountDemo</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="n" scope="application" value="${n+1}"/>
<h3><p>Welcome </p> you are ${n} visitor of this page</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following code for displaying how many users visited the page. When I run this code in tomcat it's showing error for http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core. What's wrong with this? The folder structure which i have created is count/WEB-INF/lib. In lib I copied jstl and standards jar files. In parent folder I stored the jsp page.

Comment: can you post error please, with stack trace

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
 This was the error generated.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info